# In Postgres, does putting an INDEX on a column speed up RANK() and DENSE_RANK()?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I'm using `RANK()` and `DENSE_RANK()` to produce more terse primary key columns from various CHAR and INT columns.  Postgres is my database system, but I suppose the answer to my question may apply to more systems.

My question is this: Would it be faster to create an INDEX for the columns used in `DENSE_RANK() OVER (...)` ahead of running the query?  I'm only going to be running the query once, so adding the INDEX would need to speed things up enough to "pay off" the time spent indexing.

Comment: Check the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html)

Comment: Probably not. Both `rank()` and  `dense_rank()` are *Window Functions*. With the exception of the final sort window functions are the last step in SQL execution, all filtering and grouping already completed. The *proper* way to determine would be: phase 1 run without creating index, phase 2: undo the actions of phase 1, phase 3: create index, finally phase 4: rerun phase 1. Record times for 1, 3, and 4. Then decide. But for a 1 time run why bother. BTW This sounds like a very bad idea; how do future inserts/updates fit into these generated values. Just generate a sequence.

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, I didn't know about EXPLAIN.